# Twitter Search API relevance

Tags: php, api, twitter

I'm build a PHP script that runs on a hourly cron job to find tweets of any user that contains a particular hashtag. I then save the tweets found by the API on a database. These tweets are from people participating in a simple contest where they are supposed to tweet something creative about the contest and use a hashtag.

The script I have so far e quite simple and seems to work (using [Abraham\TwitterOAuth](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth)):

```
$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, 
$access_token, $access_token_secret);

$json = $connection->get("search/tweets", ["q" => 'contesthashtag', 
"result_type" => "recent", "count" => 100, "tweet_mode" => "extended"]);

if($json!=null && $json->statuses && $json->statuses!=null && is_array($json->statuses) && count($json->statuses)>0)
  {
    foreach($json->statuses as $tweet)
    {
      if($tweet->in_reply_to_status_id==null && $tweet->in_reply_to_user_id==null && $tweet->in_reply_to_screen_name==null)
      {
        echo "<tr>
          <td>".$tweet->id_str."</td>
          <td>".$tweet->created_at."</td>
          <td>".$tweet->user->name."</td>
          <td>".$tweet->user->screen_name."</td>
          <td>".$tweet->full_text."</td>
        </tr>";
      }
    }
  }
```

Anyway, [reading the Twitter Search API docs](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/overview/standard.html), I noticed something:

> Before digging in, it’s important to know that the standard search API is focused on relevance and not completeness. This means that some Tweets and users may be missing from search results.

Does this mean that some of the tweets with the hashtag I'm looking for may not be found? What is `relevance` here? Does it mean that a user with few followers won't appear in the results?

I really don't need to get tweets older than a few hours, but really need to make sure I get all of them so that no one stay out of the contest.

Comment: Maybe you would be better off using Twitter's streaming api.

Comment: Thanks Jonas, I'm not familiar with the streaming api but will check it out.